# MembershipUser.ChangePassword fails without warning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

If I call user.ChangePassword(oldpass,newpass), and the old password is wrong, or the new password does not meet the provider's complexity requirement , the method fails without warning. is there any way i can find out if there is an error and what the error was.

I can always put these checks in my code, but there should be a way to do it using the Membership APIs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The [`ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx) method only returns a simple bool for success/fail.

Your best option on fail would be to display a generic message to the user stating all possible failure reasons... e.g.

Failed to Change Password.
This may have occured because:

- The Old Password was incorrect
- The New Password failed to meet the required complexibility
- New Passwords must be 8 chars long and contain at least 2 numeric characters. (or whatever)

If you want to give more specific information, then as you said, you would need to implement a rules checker in your own code and relay information to the user based on that check.